# Attempt to de-reference a null object in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am getting below error while running the below test class -

```
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object at 
Class.SmartAccountDetailsExtension_Test.testSmartAccountDetailsExtension: line 11, column 1
```

Class -

```
public class SmartAccountDetailsExtension {

   private Smart_Account__C smartaccount;
   private ApexPages.StandardController stdController ;
public SmartAccountDetailsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.smartaccount= (Smart_Account__C)stdController.getRecord();
        this.stdController = stdController;///This line is not getting civered in test class
    } // End Method

 }
```

Test Class -

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class SmartAccountDetailsExtension_Test {

    static ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    Static List<Smart_Account__c> sm;

    public static testMethod void testSmartAccountDetailsExtension(){

        sm=[SELECT id, Name FROM Smart_Account__c limit 1];
        controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(sm[0]);
        SmartAccountDetailsExtension sad = new SmartAccountDetailsExtension(controller);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the test but in you're constructor: 
In your constructor, you're referring to `stdController.getRecord()` but the value (the crtl value) you're passing to the constructor is called just `controller`:

`public SmartAccountDetailsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController **controller**){`

So you need to replace `stdController.getRecord()` with `controller.getRecord()`, and replace this: `this.stdController = stdController;` with `this.stdController = controller;`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized you list

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class SmartAccountDetailsExtension_Test {

    static ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    Static List<Smart_Account__c> sm;

    public static testMethod void testSmartAccountDetailsExtension(){
        sm = List<Smart_Account__c>();
        sm=[SELECT id, Name FROM Smart_Account__c limit 1];
        controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(sm[0]);
        SmartAccountDetailsExtension sad = new SmartAccountDetailsExtension(controller);
    }
}
```

Apex Class:

```
public class SmartAccountDetailsExtension {

   private Smart_Account__C smartaccount;
   private ApexPages.StandardController stdController ;
public SmartAccountDetailsExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        this.smartaccount= (Smart_Account__C)controller.getRecord();
        this.stdController = controller;///This line is not getting civered in test class
    } // End Method

 }
```

As best practice you should create test data inside your test class instead of using SeeAllData=true

Comment: still it is showing error in this '''SmartAccountDetailsExtension sad = new SmartAccountDetailsExtension(controller);'''' line

Comment: what is error. Please modify your question with error.

Comment: I have modified my question wth error

Comment: i have updated code. as Yonantan mentioned you are using stdController which you have not initialized so use controller which you are passing in constructor.